# If I mount the ISO where is the kernel initrd for the OS installer

Tags: kernel, mount, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to make a KVM installing from ubuntu iso.  In order to use the `cmdline` argument in the XML to kickstart the vm ([as i asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49012747/install-ubuntu-16-04-with-libvirt-and-kickstart)) I need to figure out where the kernel intrd and kernel are on a iso disk or how I can access this so I Can simply dowload the ISO then mount and deploy a vps with a kickstart script

I understand I can do this

```
sudo mount -o loop path/to/iso/file/YOUR_ISO_FILE.ISO /media/iso
```

But then I'm still unsure what I point the directory too for the cmd line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `casper` directory for the `initrd.lz` file, in your case

```
cd /media/iso/casper
```

should bring you to the correct directory.

---

You can find a file, if you know part of its name by (for example)

```
find . -iname "*initrd*"
```

or if it is in a directory with only 'sudo' permissions

```
sudo find . -iname "*initrd*"
```

when you have changed directory to the mountpoint.

Comment: Do you happen to know the Kernel as well?

Comment: Do you mean `vmlinuz`? It is in the same directory.

Comment: Yeah needed the `vmlinuz`

Comment: I'm glad I could help :-)